# How to verify passphrase of pem certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate

As the title says. I can verify passphrase easily with php's `openssl_pkcs12_read` for p12 certs, but it seems like there isn't similar function for pems. Maybe it's impossible to do this with pems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried php's `openssl_x509_read`? [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-read.php).

Or, if you're just using openssl ,`openssl x509 -text`.

Comment: But there is no passphrase option, how will it check that it's valid?

Comment: After looking a little closer at the PHP documentation, I think you want `openssl_pkey_get_private`, which takes both the password and .pem file as arguments.  For `openssl` (it certainly appears you're trying to stick with PHP, though), try `openssl rsa -in keyfile.pem` with the `passin` argument.

Answer (score 18):

Try this if you don't mind the password being on the command-line and in the shell history:

```
openssl rsa -noout -in YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE.pem -passin "pass:YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

or with the password in a file:

```
openssl rsa -noout -in YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE.pem -passin "file:/PATH/PASSWORD_FILE.TXT"
```

Or build around something like this:

```
if openssl rsa -noout -in "$KEYFILE" -passin "pass:$PASSWORD" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo OK
else
    echo "Wrong password"
fi
```

Comment: For a correct password, there is no output, for the wrong one, there is an error. For password reading, I'm using `read -s -p "Password:" PASSWORD`

Answer (score 3):

One can also test the pass phrase without passing their password by using:

```
openssl rsa -noout -in YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE.pem
```

If passphrase is entered correctly, then no return.

If passphrase is entered incorrectly, then will return error:

PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_pbe_crypt_ex:pkcs12 cipherfinal error:../crypto/pkcs12/p12_decr.c:86:maybe wrong password